# Enforcing PIN on Windows Store Apps (8.1)

Tags: security, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

We want to enforce at minimum a PIN and an inactivity timeout on our Windows Store App.

The Exchange Active Sync (EAS) policy API looks like the right thing to use but it should be used with much caution.

You can either check for compliance or enforce compliance

- MaxInactivityTimeLockValue should work for the minimum time before the screen locks

The trouble is that the check RequestedPolicy.CheckCompliance() never succeeds. I have tried it on a Surface 2 RT that has lock screen set to 2 mins and a Windows 8.1 Desktop that had a screen saver set to display after 1 minute and show password on resume.

Both of these fail the following check

```
RequestedPolicy.MaxInactivityTimeLock = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
ComplianceResult = RequestedPolicy.CheckCompliance();
```

I would expect ComplianceResult.Compliant to be True but it never is. Has anyone ever managed to get this work as expected?

**EDIT**

<del>**Once set i cannot see any way of undoing this on my Surface RT.**</del>

I have found a way that the user can do it in this article, [Reset EAS Policies](http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2013/03/how-to-reset-exchange-activesync-policies-in-windows-8.html) However I still cannot see a way of unenforcing in code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you can only check for compliance of a Policy if one has already been set. If no policy has been set, even if you would be compliant with it, CheckCompliance will return false.

**There is no way of Enforcing PIN** there is only a way of **disabling** what Microsoft calls "convenience logons", these are:

- Picture password
- PIN

Seeing as any user would have needed to already have a user name and password to get the account on the Windows 8.1 device there will always be at least a username\password combo